# How to define of initializing generic type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm writing the function like this

```
func issueArrayFromResponse(response: DataResponse<Any>) -> Result<[Issue]> {}
```

However this kind of function appear many time, such as repoArrayFromResponse, gistArrayFromRespnse and so on. So I tried to make these functions into one.

```
func arrayFromResponse<T>(response: DataResponse<Any>) -> Result<[T]> {}
```

The problem is I don't have initializer for type T and don't know how to achieve it. In case `issueArrayFromResponse`, I have a class `Issue` and it has initializer: init(json: [[String: Any]]), so i was able to write

```
issue = Issue(json: item)
```

However, in case `arrayFromResponse<T>`, the compiler says `'T' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`

How can I make initializer for T?

Comment: Make a protocol that has the initializer you want to use. Then use `<T: MyProtocol>`.

Comment: thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to make protocol.
You can make such protocol:

```
protocol ResultProtocol {   
}
```

and confirm all your classes to this protocol

```
class Issue: ResultProtocol {
    init(json: String) {

    }
}
```

then you can:

```
func arrayFromResponse<T: ResultProtocol>(response: DataResponse<Any>) -> Result<[T]> {

    return Result<[T]>()

}
```